# Removing space on one side of dollar sign using sed

Tags: regex, text, sed

I want to convert

```
Some text $ latex code  $ some more text
```

to

```
Some text $latex code$ some more text
```

using sed (or something else) with reasonable efficiency.

I tried to remove the first space using

```
sed -e 's/\$\s*/\$/g'
```

but that makes `$ some` to `$some` which is undesirable. Likewise I can do it for the second $, but that will also create similar issue at the front.

I then tried capturing group like this:

```
sed -e 's/\$\s*\(.*\)\s*\$/\$\1\$/g'
```

which is not working (maybe because (.*) group includes \s and $?). Its output is

```
Some text $latex code  $ some more text
```

So how can I do this efficiently? It would be great if the answer can also accommodate $$'s spanning two lines.

Comment: I suggest to use a space if you want to remove a space.

Comment: I am sorry I don't know what you mean. I basically learnt all my sed reading examples on this site. Can you explain?

Comment: Use a space and not \s.

Comment: Okay, I will try and report

Comment: That did help, but didn't solve the whole problem. Now I can remove one space on either side if its present.  If I have to replace multiple spaces (as in the example given above) it doesn't work. I tried using ` *` but that is behaving just like `\s*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **GNU** sed:

```
sed 's/\$ \+/$/; s/ \+\$/$/2' file
```

or with `\s` (matches space and tab):

```
sed 's/\$\s\+/$/; s/\s\+\$/$/2' file
```

Output:

```
Some text $latex code$ some more text
```

> `\+`: means that the preceding expression must match at least one time or multiple times

> `$`: dollar sign, no special meaning here

> `2`: only replace the 2nd match of the regex

Comment: It works for multiple spaces; only does something weird if `Some text` is removed, but that's fine. Can you please tell what are these `\+`, `$`  and `/2`?

Comment: @physicophilic: I've updated my answer. This might help: `man 7 regex` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Isn't the `$` sign meant to be escaped? I asked about it because you leave two `$` signs unescaped

Comment: sed's `s` command uses this syntax `s/regex/replace/flags`. If you use `$` in regex section without a backslash it is a special character and it marks the end of a line. With a backslash it has no special meaning. A `$` in replace section has no special meaning. Flags are optional.